# When entering data, should the user be authenticated on clicking "Create" or "Save"?

Tags: user-behavior, web-app, user-expectation, security, authentication

Having the two options:

1. Check if user authenticated upon "Save" button click (when the input dialog is shown and filled in with the data)
2. Check if user authenticated upon "Create" button click (before the input dialog is shown)

in both scenaria if user is not auth'ed an overlay is given with the login details input and login button.

which one do you choose and why?

Comment: Who are your users? When would be the most opportune time for them?

Comment: Users are commenters mainly. Haven't a clue.

Comment: It would be useful to find out. :)

Answer (score 3):

As a user I'd expect to be asked to login before the input dialog is shown. If I'm shown the input dialog I expect the login to be unnecessary, and if otherwise I'd consider it as a violation of the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: I kind of agree. But showing the login dialog *before* the input results in a nasty UI transition - when a user gets auth'ed he should get brought to the input - which might be a bit of a surprise for him. So I'd day it does go against POLA

Comment: True, but I'd say in a lesser degree with respect to the other option. Also, depending on the context, the user should be aware of the fact that a logon will be necessary for certain operations. The important thing is (in my opinion) to make it happen when the user himself/herself expects it.

Answer (score 1):

How about you make the form a little larger and show both login info & create form fields into the same dialog?

So:

1. Check if user is authenticated upon clicking on the "Create" button
2. If logged in, just show input fields in dialog
3. If not logged in, show login fields in top section and the create form at the bottom section of the dialog

That way there's no surprises that you need to login to create and clicking on the "Create" button actually allows you to create.

Comment: Sounds like a good choice. I'll think about it. the problem is - is a user is not registered/forgot his password - I'll be turning my input into 100% security screen which isn't ideal

Comment: Oh I would treat those as edge case flows and redirect the user back to the regular sign up/forgot password process. i.e. have a link next to the login box for sign up & forgot password

Answer (score 0):

How about showing the link to the log in form as a button "log in to comment" instead of the input field?

Then, to make it user friendly, store the current link in a session, have the user log in (or register) and redirect to the page where he wanted to place a comment

Makes the process very clear.